# Using IF statements with 2 comboboxes to determine a textbox's value?

Tags: vba, if-statement, combobox

Very simple code. I followed another example from here to use but it only works one way. If I select combobox7 first as a "yes" and Combobox8 as a "No" it will pass it, but only if I click it twice, meaning I have to reselect "No" then "Yes" on Combobox7 in order to get the desired result. Bottom line is, ComboBox7 = "No" and ComboBox8 = "No" Then TextBox8.value = "Fail" Else "Pass".
I don't really dab on VBA at all so I am not even as high as a beginner at this, so please be gentle. I've been called many rude names on this site just because I don't know it as well as your moderators, causing me to leave this site completely, but I can't find an answer to this one. Its acting erratic. Can anyone help in a kind manner? Again, lower than a noob here! Not looking to be put down, just trying to make sense of this. Thank you.

```
Private Sub ComboBox7_Change()
    If ComboBox7.Value = "No" And ComboBox8.Value Like "No" Then
        TextBox8.Value = "Fail"
    Else
        TextBox8.Value = "Pass"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Kudos for asking an answerable question that includes your code! Sorry you've had less-than-stellar experiences on this site before. Do note that meta-ranting is largely noise that distracts from and buries the actual question, and is frowned upon - I would warmly recommend editing it out.

Comment: That said, the `Like` operator is typically used with wildcards. Without them, there's little need for it. Wouldn't `=` work just as well?

Comment: If I put the = it doesn't work at all. I've tried 4 different ways of doing it but they will only work when 1 combobox is changed and no effect when the other is changed. The code is very simple, I just don't get why its not liking it or what's causing it to do something different. There aren't any other subs for any of those comboboxes or textbox so I don't get why its doing this.

Comment: Could `ComboBox8.Value` be `"No "` or `"  No"`? If so, try trimming (`Trim`) the values when you populate the combobox list. Is `ComboBox7` populated the same way?

Answer (score 2):

You just have to add the same again for the other control. For instance:

```
Private Sub ComboBox7_Change()
    If ComboBox7.Value = "No" And ComboBox7.Value Like "No" Then
        TextBox8.Value = "Fail"
    Else
        TextBox.Value = "Pass"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox8_Change()
    If ComboBox7.Value = "No" And ComboBox8.Value Like "No" Then
        TextBox8.Value = "Fail"
    Else
        TextBox8.Value = "Pass"
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit**: This is because the update to the textbox is only being fired by changing ComboBox7 in your example. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes! This was it!!! Thank you! For a second I thought they would clash but it makes sense that it only reacts to the combobox7 since that's where the change was happening! Sorry for the brain fart, but thank you for the answer! Upvoted! Thank you so much!

Comment: @user1739280 note that you'll get a +2 reputation bonus (answerer gets +15) if you mark an answer as "accepted", by clicking the hollow green checkmark just underneath the up/down voting buttons. That will also take your question out of the ever-growing list of "unanswered" questions. Cheers!